# How to use python's list comprehensions to execute the following matlab code?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, list-comprehension

Okay so in Matlab I have a 1D vector of 'scores':

```
Scores = [3;7;3;2;1;5;1];
```

What I want to do is subtract 0.5 from all of the elements that are less than 3. In matlab I can do this:

```
Scores(Scores < 3) = Scores(Scores < 3 ) - 0.5;
```

I can then use this result to obtain a boolean vector representing the indices of the Scores I would like to delete corresponding objects for:

```
animals2Delete = animalIDs(Scores < 2)
```

so:
if my list of animalIDs was as follows:

```
animalIDs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

My matlab code could return:

```
animals2Delete = [4,5,7]
```

My question is: Can I do this using pythons list comprehension in an efficient manner? Or do I need to use numpy or some other package?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what the output is you want. Is `animals2Delete` a temporary  result or do you actually want this list?

Comment: Sorry - I was trying to give a simplified case but obviously added some confusion. What I actually have in Matlab is a mx4 matrix of bounding boxes with a corresponding vector of BoxIDs. These represent people being tracked. I also have a vector of corresponding box scores indicating the confidence of the object being tracked being 'good'.

I want to find the BoxIDs corresponding to low box scores so as to delete those boxes.

Comment: SO I want the list 'animals2Delete'in the example so I can then find the animals corresponding to those IDs and delete them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's doable but in my opinion would be easier and cleaner with numpy.

Without numpy:

```
Scores = [3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1]
Scores = [i-0.5 if i<3 else i for i in Scores]

animalIDs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
animals2Delete = [id for id, score in zip(animalIDs, Scores) if score < 2]
#this could be made in a number of ways, this is just one way.
```

With numpy logic is more like in Matlab

```
import numpy as np

Scores = np.array( [3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1] )
Scores[ Scores < 3 ] = Scores[ Scores < 3 ] - 0.5

animalIDs = np.array( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] )
animals2Delete = animalIDs[ Scores < 2 ]
#Again, just one way to do it.
```

Comment: Great! I found I could also write: [i for i,v in enumerate(Scores) if y<min]. That was after subtracting the 0.5 in another step. The thing is that I am needing to append new IDs the whole time and appending in numpy is very expensive apparently? Thanks a lot for the reply

Comment: It's definitely at least cleaner to append lists.

Comment: There is no need for `np.where` here. Also, `Scores[Score < 3] -= 0.5` will be sufficient for your first operation.

Comment: This is very true. I tried to follow the logic of the original question as closely as possible.

Comment: Well, you don't really need the `np.where` as it adds overhead thats not needed and makes the code look more complex than its MatLab counterpart.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np
Scores = np.array([3,7,3,2,1,5,1])
animalIDs = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

just create a boolean mask where  the score is smaller or equal to 2

```
animals2Delete = Scores <= 2
```

and then apply this mask on the animal IDs:

```
animalIDs[animals2Delete]
# returns array([4, 5, 7])
```

or doing it in one step:

```
animalIDs[Scores <= 2]
```

This does not use list comprehensions but numpys optimized iterations. The result, at least, should be as you wanted it.

Comment: But I am needing to append to the array a lot - is this not very expensive in numpy as it needs to create a whole new array with an extra element?

Comment: I actually don't know if appending to a numpy array is much more ineffecient than appending to a python list. Python lists can be increased more effiecient but indexing is slower, Numpy is slow during appending and fast while indexing. Depends on your use-case which to choose. You can also convert to/from numpy arrays as needed.

Comment: @PeterTurner Appending to a numpy array requires a copy of the entire array, appending to a list is very fast as the data does not need to be contiguous. The exact same effects will be seen in mathematica, although I think its likely they pre-allocate larger arrays than requested exactly because of this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like all the elements with Score < 2.5 will be deleted.

```
animals2Delete=[]
index=0

for i in Scores:
    if i < 2.5:
        animals2Delete.append(animalIDs[index])
    index+=1
```

Let me know if I got your problem incorrectly.

Comment: and you can add  `zip` also :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to define `Scores` as a `numpy` array

```
import numpy as np
Scores = np.array([3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1])
```

to subtract `0.5` try:

```
Scores[Scores >= 3] = Scores[Scores >= 3] - 0.5
```

you can define `animals2Delete` as follow:

```
animals2Delete = np.arange(Scores.size)[Scores <= 2]
```

ps: python iterable index start from `0` like C.